# Why won't my array use the map method even though it's actually an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I console.log the state of users after I set it as an array of objects from the github api and it displays as an array. However, I can't use the map function like this (if I decided to use it in a child component using props):

```
this.state.users.map((user)=>(
 <UserItem key={user.id} user={user}/>
))
```

I get an error: "TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function"
And It's pretty confusing because it is an array. It looks like this in the props viewer:
[image: Array Users] As you can see. Users is an array. I don't understand but I could be missing something very simple from lack of coffee. Thanks for your help! I appreciate it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
// import UserItem from './components/users/UserItem';
import Users from './components/users/Users';
// import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    users: {},
    loading: false
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      {loading: true}
    )
    const res = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/users')

    this.setState(
      { 
        loading: false,
        users: res.data,
      }
    
    )

    // console.log(res.data)
  }

  render() {


    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container">
          <Users loading={this.state.loading} users={this.state.users} />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial value of `this.state.users` is an object. Hence the error `map is not a function`

```
state = {
    users: {}, <--- object
    loading: false
}
```

The API call happens after the component has mounted for the first time in the `componentDidMount` life cycle method and the value of `state.users` gets populated with the data.

The component has to render with the initial state on the first render.

Change the value of `users` to be an empty array in the initial state.

```
state = {
    users: [],  // change initial value of users to be an empty array
    loading: false
}
```

Comment: Oh gosh I'm facepalming so hard rn. Thanks a bunch!